# How to get target_id column from GAIA DR3 basic search?

Tags: gaia, esa

When using the GAIA search through the website, the target_id column seems to pop up without any displayed column specified and disappears just as mysteriously. Does anybody know how to trigger that column to display when downloading data?

Thank you